# Add button in android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I trying to add a button beside HealthyApp, but no luck .

This is my initial code and image

```
  final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[image]

I want to add a delete button beside HealthyApp but the HealthyApp title gone.

```
 final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_button, null);
        Button mTitleTextView = (Button) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("Delete");
        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

[image]

**delete_task**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d9d9d9"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="Delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/to_do"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="No List Found"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_login"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list_todo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Add toolbar inside your xml . and use `NoActionBar` in your activity theme .**

add these toolbar in your xml on top

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#131313"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00aaaaaa"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

add these theme in your activity in Menifest.xml

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

and add these code in your activity ....

```
Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();;
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Output:-

[image: fg]

**OR**

**I think it is possible with the icon only .....**

use this item in menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/YourImage"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

**Note:- use `android:icon="@drawable/YourImageWithTextDelete"` put here your image .....**

Comment: but I don't want to use icon, just android button

Comment: then you have to use custom Toolbar ..... include toolbar inside your xml .... and use `NoActionBar` in your activity theme .....

Comment: Sir, I add `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` inside my delete_task layout, but the button is added below action bar.

Comment: add this in your menifest.xml in your activity tag `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125221/discussion-between-hoo-and-sushildlh).

Answer (score 3):

In your Activity layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/YourColor"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:theme="@style/about_toolbar"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/YourText"
             />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/YourText"
        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_acticity_layout);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       }

       // ... your other methods
}
```

In your Manifest, Activity tag

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/YourActivityString"
        android:theme="@style/YourTheme" />
```

In your style.xml

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">...</item> <!-- declare your styles -->
</style>
```

If you need a better code sample: Just download https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare , It has the example toolbar.